# i can not write more than one object on a file in java

Tags: java, file, object

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    static ArrayList<test> testArrey = new ArrayList<test>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        output(new test(18, "aren"));
        output(new test(22, "ahmad"));
        input();
        read();
    }

    public static void read() {
        for (test a : testArrey) {
            System.out.println(a.age);
        }
    }
    public static void input() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("open.ses");
            ObjectInputStream ObjectInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);

            Object a1 = ObjectInput.readObject();
            test b1 = (test) a1;
            testArrey.add(b1);

            Object a2 = ObjectInput.readObject();
            test b2 = (test) a2;
            testArrey.add(b2);

            ObjectInput.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("input error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void output(test a) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream  fileOut = new FileOutputStream("open.ses");
            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            objectOut.writeObject(a);

            objectOut.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("output error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static class test implements Serializable {
        int age ;
        String  name ;

        public test(int age , String name ) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see a called output() method two time with new to object of (test)as argument ,and it must write two object on (open.ses)file but when i want to call (.readobject)two times it gives me an error that says one object is saved ............

how to write more than one object with the help of method like the one i wrote ??

Comment: Serialize 'testArray' after adding your objects to it. Add an empty constructor to `test` (which should start with a capital as should all class names)

Comment: Open the stream, and only close it once you've written all objects.

Comment: your `output` method overwrites any existing file. If you call it twice, the second call will overwrite the file from the first call.

Comment: `new FileOutputStream("open.ses")` ← That immediately wipes out any existing file.  I suggest checking if any of the [constructors of FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#constructor-summary) can append to a file instead of overwriting it.